# Binary buffer literal

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, literals, string-literals

I would like to create a Buffer from a *binary string literal*, like you would do in C or many other languages.

Basically I'd like to obtain a buffer that contains `\xFF\x00Hello\xFFWorld\x00How\xFFare\x00You\xFF?`, where each ascii character and escaped hex value takes one byte each.

Is there an easy way to do this with the latest JavaScript versions or Nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Buffer.from("\xFF\x00Hello\xFFWorld\x00How\xFFare\x00You\xFF?", "latin1")
```